# How to make sure a background task was ended successfully

Tags: ios, xcode, background, task

I am having an issue about background task confusing me in a few days. To make it simple in description, I separate my project to this experiment.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background;
    NSTimer *t;
}

- (void)beginBackgroundTask;
- (void)endBackgroundTask;
- (void)printIt;

- (IBAction)startBGTaskPressed:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    t = nil;
    background = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

    [self beginBackgroundTask];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Internal use

- (void)beginBackgroundTask {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    background = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

        [self endBackgroundTask];
    }];

    NSLog(@"background created: %d", background);

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(printIt)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];

        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:t
                                     forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes]; // NSDefaultRunLoopMode
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
    });
}

- (void)endBackgroundTask {
    NSLog(@"Ending background: %d", background);

    if (t!=nil) {
        [t invalidate];
        t = nil;
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:background];
    background = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}

- (void)printIt {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    NSLog(@"remaining: %f", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining]);
}

#pragma mark - Actions

- (IBAction)startBGTaskPressed:(id)sender {
    if (background==UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
        NSLog(@"background not ready --> create");

        [self beginBackgroundTask];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"background ready --> return");
    }
}

@end
```

Short description: In `- (void)viewDidLoad`, I create a background task by `- (void)beginBackgroundTask`. When the background task is expired (3 mins, although 10 mins is mentioned in some documents) after the app enters background, `- (void)endBackgroundTask` is implemented in which the timer is cleared and the background task is ended.

But what I see from Xcode is strange when I pause the program execution in XCode debug, I see:

```
Thread 3
Queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
0 mach_msg_trap
7 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run]
8 __37-[ViewController beginBackgroundTask]_block_invoke14
9 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
12 _pthread_wqthread
```

As I may understand, `8 __37-[ViewController beginBackgroundTask]_block_invoke14` is the block of `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` in `- (void)beginBackgroundTask`. But why Xcode still shows `7 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run]`?

Did I do something wrong in `- (void)endBackgroundTask`? Xcode does not warn me in this function.

How can we make sure a background task is ended successfully? Can Xcode Instruments help?

Any replies is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hope that someone else is able to help you. ;)